# Will members be compiled into subclass's .class file?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass, .class-file

In java, will inherited members(static or instance, method or field) be compiled into subclass's .class file?

Or just keep a link to the super class's relavent member?

Comment: Short answer: Neither. --- The only thing the subclass `.class` file contains, is the name of the superclass. And any `super` references in the subclass code, including implicit constructor calls.

Comment: just curious - why do you need that?

Comment: @khachik I'm just curious about it. Not really need it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as class files are concerned, inherited members are not copied into subclasses. Here is [relevant documentation from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html) (emphasis added):

> - `fields[]`
>     Each value in the fields table must be a `field_info` (§4.5) structure giving a complete description of a field in this class or interface. The fields table includes only those fields that are declared by this class or interface. **It does not include items representing fields that are inherited from superclasses or superinterfaces.**
> - `methods[]` Each value in the methods table must be a method_info (§4.6) structure giving a complete description of a method in this class or interface. [...] The `method_info` structures represent all methods declared by this class or interface type, including instance methods, class methods, instance initialization methods (§2.9), and any class or interface initialization method (§2.9). **The methods table does not include items representing methods that are inherited from superclasses or superinterfaces.**